# Piping stream into tar on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, tar, gzip

I am trying to pipe a tar/gzip archive into tar to decompress it. The script I have is part of a self extracting installer, where my archive is appended to the script. This works fine on linux, and the script looks like this:

```
export TMPDIR=`mktemp -d /tmp/selfextract.XXXXXX`

echo "TEMP: $TMPDIR"

ARCHIVE=`awk '/^__ARCHIVE_BELOW__/ {print NR + 1; exit 0; }' $0`


tail -n+$ARCHIVE $0 | tar xz -C $TMPDIR


exit 0

__ARCHIVE_BELOW__
```

The tar archive as a string is after the **ARCHIVE_BELOW** but I omitted it from here since it's huge.

However, when I do this on FreeBSD I get the following error:

```
tar: Failed to open '/dev/sa0'
```

I read that this is because free BSD expects to read from that device by default and you can tell it to read from stdin by passing `-f -` like so:

```
tail -n+$ARCHIVE $0 | tar zxf - -C $TMPDIR
```

However, when I do this I just get the error:

```
tar: Damaged tar archive
tar: Retrying...
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here? I need to do it this way (Via piping) for efficiency reasons.

Thanks

Comment: Adding -v should at least tell you where it the process. You can also try to use -j instead of -z but it might be irrelevant with newer version.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not give me any more information or help resolve the issue. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 0):

In the first command:

> echo $ARCHIVE | tar xz -C $TMPDIR

This is piping the file name into tar, not the contents of the file. How this is working is beyond me.

In the final command you list:

> tail -n+$ARCHIVE $0 | tar zxf - -C $TMPDIR

I think this is specifying the file name as the argument to "tail", which probably isn't going to work either. Even if ${ARCHIVE} is a number, you still can't pipe the tail of an archive to tar, you need to give it the whole archive. Why are you calling tail here at all? A better solution might be:

> tar xzvf ${ARCHIVE} -C ${TMPDIR}

Comment: Sorry, I tried to simplify this example and it seems I managed part of it. I have added a much fuller example above that should make this clearer.

Comment: I think the answer that getting the tail of an archive doesn't work still applies.

Comment: Why does this work on linux then?